# How to display the feed of a SharePoint Blog to its parent site?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have created a "blog" site/workspace on our SharePoint site and want the posts to be visible on the home page. The ugliest way around it is using a 'web frame' but I'd rather display it as a feed of sorts.

There isn't a web part that seems to cater to that (unless someone tells me otherwise) and SharePoint Designer cannot be used.

I've heard that it might be possible to use JavaScript to achieve this and was wondering if I could get some direction for this?

**Edit**

Due the locked-down nature of SharePoint 2010 that we're using, we cannot use the RSS or Content Query web parts. The closest thing is the XML Viewer web part.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the Content Query Web Part. It's a standard Web Part you can point at another site and generate a list of hyperlinks given a set of filters and other options.

Comment: I think our version is a little locked down, so we don't have the Content Query Web Part, sadly.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Comment: @Az:You need to have publishing feature enabled in order to have content query web part

Comment: Hi we're using SharePoint 2010 and the version our team is using is a basic one with many of the features disabled.

Comment: If you are using SharePoint Server, edit a page, go to Editing Tools -> Insert in the ribbon, click on Web Part, and in the "Content Rollup" category, you should see "Content Query". This Web Part may not be available in SharePoint Foundation (the free edition) ...

Comment: I've got Content Rollup > XML Viewer?